# Sort list by a condition on parameters

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following list

```
list={{{0,0,0},0},{{0,0,1},a},{{0,0,-1},-a},{{1,0,1},b},{{1,0,0},-b},{{1,1,1},a+b},{{1,1,1},a-b},{{-1,0,-1},{-a-b}},{{-1,0,-1},{-a+b}}};
```

how can this list be sorted such that a>b>0, therefore the expected result would be

```
list={{{1,1,1},a+b},{{0,0,1},a},{{1,0,1},b},{{1,1,1},a-b},{{0,0,0},0},{{-1,0,-1},{-a+b}},{{1,0,0},-b},{{0,0,-1},-a},{{-1,0,-1},{-a-b}}};
```

in this specific example we also have that `2b>a` however it is not that important.

Answer (score 4):

After fixing your list (the last two items had a list wrapped around the second element), the following works:

```
list = {{{0, 0, 0}, 0}, {{0, 0, 1}, a}, {{0, 0, -1}, -a}, {{1, 0, 1}, b}, {{1, 0, 0}, -b}, {{1, 1, 1}, a + b}, {{1, 1, 1}, a - b}, {{-1, 0, -1}, -a - b}, {{-1, 0, -1}, -a + b}};

Sort[list, FullSimplify[#[[2]] > #2[[2]], a > b > 0 && 2 b > a] &]
(* {{{1, 1, 1}, a + b}, {{0, 0, 1}, a}, {{1, 0, 1}, b}, {{1, 1, 1}, a - b}, {{0, 0, 0}, 0}, {{-1, 0, -1}, -a + b}, {{1, 0, 0}, -b}, {{0, 0, -1}, -a}, {{-1, 0, -1}, -a - b}} *)
```

This works by supplying a [custom comparison function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html#359818967) to [`Sort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html) that simplifies "left">"right" given the assumptions on `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ordering = Reverse @ 
   Ordering[list[[All, 2]] /. FindInstance[a > b > 0 && 2 b > a, {a, b}][[1]]];

list[[ordering]]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1, 1}, a + b}, {{0, 0, 1}, a}, {{1, 0, 1}, b}, {{1, 1, 1}, a - b}, 
>  {{0, 0, 0}, 0}, {{-1, 0, -1}, -a + b}, {{1, 0, 0}, -b}, {{0, 0, -1}, -a}, 
>  {{-1, 0, -1}, -a - b}}
> ```

This should be faster for long lists.